# How is "at most one arrow" used to proof a special category gives rise to a preorder set?

Tags: category-theory

I'm working on exercise 2 on page 1 of [Basic Category Theory](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~ooste110/syllabi/catsmoeder.pdf) By Jaap van Oosten.

The problem is:

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a category such that $\mathcal{C}_0$ is a set, and such that for any two objects $X, Y$ of $\mathcal{C}$ there is **at most one arrow**: $x \rightarrow y$, then $\mathcal{C}_0$ is a preorder set.

I try to prove this by using the definition of preorder set:

- element: all objects in $\mathcal{C}$
- binary relation: $f: a \rightarrow b$ is corresponding to $a \le b$.
- reflexivity: implied by identity morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$.
- transitivity: implied by composition of $\mathcal{C}$.

It seems the condition **at most one arrow** is not used anywhere. Does my proof work? Am I missing something?

Comment: If there were more than one arrow, information would be lost when you reduce $a\to b$ to $a\le b$.

Comment: The problem is with "is" a preorder set as opposed to "determines in a non-unique fashion"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the statement : any set is a preorder (for example declare all the elements to be minimal).

The correct statement of the exercise should be as follow (at least I guess this is what the author means) :

> Let $\mathsf{Pos}$ be the category whose objects are posets and whose morphisms are non decreasing maps. Let $\mathsf{Slim}$ be the category whose objects are the categories $\mathcal C$ such that $\mathcal C_0$ is a set and that for every $x,y \in \mathcal C_0$ there is at most one arrow $x \to y$ and whose morphisms are the functors between such categories.
>
> Then show that $\mathsf{Pos}$ is equivalent to $\mathsf{Slim}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Well as for the posets with one elements, I can think of $\{0\}$, $\{1\}$, $\{\emptyset\}$, etc. But I think you're right however that there is not a strict isomorphism : between two different objects one might name (label) the unique arrow between the two... I'll edit ; the important point is the equivalence.